# How can I pass file names to external commands executed from Python?

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to execute a command inside a Python script:

```
import subprocess
output_process = 
   subprocess.Popen("javac -cp C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\htmlcleaner-2.2.jar Scrapping_lastfm.java",
                    shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But I am getting an error `package org.htmlcleaner does not exist`.

If I run the javac command independently, it executes fine..

My current working directry is `C:\Users\MyUsername`.

Comment: Try the `env` argument to `Popen` with the `PATH` key set to the path of your java packages.

Comment: srry....can u please show me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not raised by python but by the java subprocess. Most likely the java machine is not finding some libraries, and that refines the problem to a PATH configuration problem, most likely
the variable CLASSPATH has not been set in the environment. to solve :

```
import shlex

JAVA_COMMAND=r"javac -cp C:\\Users\\MyUsername\\Desktop\\htmlcleaner-2.2.jar Scrapping_lastfm.java"

cmdline = shlex.split(JAVA_COMMAND)

output_process = subprocess.Popen(cmdline,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env={'CLASSPATH':'/path/to/java/packages'})
```

Comment: i tried using `env={'CLASSPATH':'C:\\jdk1.6.0_23\\bin'}` but now i am getting error `javac not recognized as internal program`...

Comment: Why are you using a raw string and doubling the backslashes?

Comment: @RanRag Try this version or my version with the full path to `javac` or also set the `PATH` variable to point to that path.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
output_process = subprocess.Popen(["javac", "-cp", 
    "C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\htmlcleaner-2.2.jar", "Scrapping_lastfm.java"],
    shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env={'ENVIRONMENTAL': '/variables/here'})
```

with whatever java-related environmental variables you have when you run `javac` normally as items in the `env` dictionary. asgs suggests you need `CLASSPATH`.

You don't have to split the command up into a list I just did that to make it easier to see the whole thing.

Comment: I think it has to be `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: Makes sense. I've rephrased and added that.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, that you have to escape the backslash (`\`) in the string. Your example is fine, however if your username is not actually MyUsername but maybe „nerd“ or any other string forming a valid escape-sequence, the command will fail.
Also make sure that you don't have spaces in the filename (or use the split syntax in the other example).

So you might want to do:

```
output_process = subprocess.Popen(["javac", "-cp", 
    "C:\\Users\\MyUsername\\Desktop\\htmlcleaner-2.2.jar", "Scrapping_lastfm.java"],
    shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```